# Using a smaller subset symbol?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, relation-symbols

I was looking at a paper and noticed they were using a thin subset symbol, like this:

[image]

I can't seem to find a command for this (and the corresponding symbol for `\subseteq`) online anywhere. How would I use this symbol?

Comment: `mathabx` may be?

Comment: this is a potential duplicate: [Importing a single symbol from a different font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

This might be what you look for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\mysub=\subset
\usepackage{mathabx}


\begin{document}
The original: $\mysub$

mathabx: $\subset$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Solution 2:**

I searched the definition of `\subset` in the `mathabx` package, and another solution without using this package is here:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
    <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * matha
    <10.95> matha10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> matha12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{matha}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mysubset}{3}{matha}{"80}

\begin{document}
The original: $\subset$

Own symbol: $\mysubset$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That seems to be the right package but loading it conflicts with one of the packages I'm using, probably amssymb. It seems like it's not easy to just load one or two symbols from a package, either

Comment: I modified my answer. Solution 2 will provide a way to load only the given symbol of `mathabx`.

Answer (score 4):

You could design your own thin subset symbol using `\scalebox`. Adjust the `.8` scaling factor however you like.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\thinsubset}{\mathrel{\scalebox{1}[.8]{$\subset$}}}
\newcommand{\thinsubseteq}{\mathrel{\scalebox{1}[.8]{$\subseteq$}}}

\begin{document}

$A\subset B\subseteq C$

$A\thinsubset B\thinsubseteq C$

\end{document}
```

A more complicated version, using `\mathpalette` will allow the symbol to be used as a subscript:

[image]

\documentclass{article}

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\thinsub}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\thin@sub\relax}}
\newcommand{\thin@sub}[2]{\m@th#1\text{\scalebox{1}[.8]{$\subset$}}}
\newcommand{\thinsubeq}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\thin@subeq\relax}}
\newcommand{\thin@subeq}[2]{\m@th#1\text{\scalebox{1}[.8]{$\subseteq$}}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\thinsubset}{\mathrel{\scalebox{1}[.8]{$\subset$}}}
\newcommand{\thinsubseteq}{\mathrel{\scalebox{1}[.8]{$\subseteq$}}}

\begin{document}

$A\subset B\subseteq C_{A\subset B\subseteq C}$

$A\thinsub B\thinsubeq C_{A\thinsub B\thinsubeq C}$

\end{document}
```